# How to install from ubuntu alternate cd

Tags: 12.04, installation

I want to ask is there any guide where it is written how to install ubuntu from the alternate cd. using text based installer. ?

Comment: What step do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no need for a guide.  Just Download the [32Bit](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-i386.iso) or the [64Bit](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso) version of Ubuntu Alternate CD, Burn the ISO to a CD, boot from the newly created CD, and follow on screen instructions.  All you have to do is answer a few questions, enter your full name, user mane, and password, then set back and let the installation finish.

To burn the ISO, just look at [Burning ISO How to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).